# NPOIでエクセルシートを編集しても、背景色のライトグレーをそのまま維持する方法を教えてください。

Tags: c#

C# でコードを書いており、NPOI を使っています。
エクセルのバージョンは、2110です。

まず、下記のような見た目の、拡張子が`.xlsx`の[エクセルファイル](https://filedropper.com/d/s/jlzgCpvBXMAbo62tR225crW21OZI5Z)があります。

[image]

これを、下記コードのようにNPOIを介して編集します。

コード:

```
private void button_editByNpoi_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string filePath = destFileName;

            IWorkbook workbook;
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fs);
            }

            /*
            //1枚目のシートを取得
            ISheet sheet = workbook.GetSheetAt(0);

            //セルを取得
            IRow row = sheet.GetRow(1);
            ICell cell = row.GetCell(1);

            //セルに書き込み
            //cell.SetCellValue("a");
            */

            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                //上書き保存する。
                workbook.Write(fs);
            }
        }
```

結果で得られるエクセルシートは下記です。

[image]

編集後、ライトグレーの背景色がきえてしまっています。ライトグレーの背景色をそのまま維持する方法はありますでしょうか？

Comment: この記事 [NPOI でセルの背景色を取得する際のマジック](http://blog.ba6.jp/2015/09/npoi.html) が何か参考になるかもしれません。

Comment: とりあえず.NET 5.0と[DotNetCore.NPOI](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DotNetCore.NPOI/), .NET Framework 4.8と[NPOI](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NPOI/)の両方で実験してみたところでは、セルに書き込みしても背景色は変わらないようです。何か使用しているフレームワークの種類か版数の問題か、Excel自身の版数とかファイルの作り方とかが関係しているのかもしれません。問題の再現するプロジェクト全体とExcelファイルをどこかで公開してみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: 確かに読み取って何もせずに書き込むだけでしかもライトグレーだけ色情報が失われますね。単純にバグか未サポート機能なのでは？ リポジトリのIssuesを探すか、それで無いなら新規に質問かバグ？のレポートとして起こしてみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: @kunif ご確認ありがとうございます。[issueの報告](https://github.com/nissl-lab/npoi/issues/695#issuecomment-973185495)はしておきました。

Comment: Issueの方でバグと判明して対応する版も決まったようなので、状況を自己回答でもしてみてください。